Making Custom Json Converter for strong type Id
I tried to create a custom JSON converter for ProductId, but the conversion didn't apply to Swagger UI. It still sees ProductId as id: { value: }. I want it to see only the GUID value as shown in the code.
public class ProductIdJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value is ProductId id)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, id.value);
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
        }
    }

    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var guid = serializer.Deserialize<Guid>(reader);
        return ProductId.Create(guid);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ProductId);
    }
}

productId
[EfCoreValueConverter(typeof(ProductConverter.ProductIdValueConverter))]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ProductConverter.ProductIdJsonConverter))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ProductConverter.ProductIdTypeConverter))]
public sealed class ProductId : ValueObjectId,IValueObjectId<ProductId>
{
    public ProductId(Guid id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    public static ProductId Create(Guid id)
    {
        return new ProductId(id);
    }

    public static ProductId CreateUnique()
    {
        return new(Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}

ValueObjectId
public abstract class ValueObjectId : ValueObject
{
    public Guid value { get;  set; }

    protected ValueObjectId(Guid id)
    {
        value = id;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}

I registered this JSON converter:
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(op => 
    {
        op.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ProductConverter.ProductIdJsonConverter());
    });

But swagger still sees the object:
enter image description here
I was trying to make custom JSON converter for productId to get custom serialization for JSON API, but this didn't work.

Could you share a demo application that can reproduce this issue?  Is the picture you shared above the result in the response body, rather than the example value in the request body?
